# magento, how sort catalogsearch collection

Tags: search, magento-1.9

How i can sort catalogsearch collection?

I found a function `_getProductCollection` but I don’t know what to do next and whether it is necessary to make changes here.

I want to sort the search by SKU, for example, user looking for a product on the site with SKU 6727, but product with SKU not in the first position, but in the 5th I want him to be 1st in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference you are using is not working is because there is no code to sort the products by category. You need to override **Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result::_getProductCollection()** and then add sorting function in it to show results in order of category id.

Try with below. Use the same reference and add this additional function to the same file.

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $this->_productCollection = $this->getListBlock()->getLoadedProductCollection();
    }
    $listOrder = $this->getRequest()->getParam('dir') ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('dir') : 'desc';
    if(!$this->getRequest()->getParam('order') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('order') == 'category'){
        $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('category' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog_product_category')),'e.entity_id = category.product_id', array('category_id'))->group('e.entity_id')->order('category.category_id '.$listOrder);
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Comment: ut how do I sort by SKU? about position as I asked in my question

Comment: Did you append your SKU on 1st line.

Comment: i don't have table catalog_product_category, it returns an error to me

Comment: but your answer is correct, I will mark it as correct

Comment: catalog_product_category does such a table exist? or maybe i need to use another table?

Comment: it doesn't help bring me product with search SKU first on the list

Comment: i need results in order of SKU